# How does ASP.NET's Authentication module work?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I can not make it clear about how the asp.net's authentication work,I set the following configuration according to the help document and google:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- 

    Login.aspx and the random_code_img.aspx does not need authentication 
    But excluding the above files,all the page are protected.
    -->
    <location path="Login.aspx">

    </location>
    <location path="random_code_img.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        ..........
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now in the login.aspx.cs:

Within the method loginButton_click:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
    username,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    isPersistent,
    "",
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

  // Encrypt the ticket.
  string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

  // Create the cookie.
  Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

  // Redirect back to the protected URL.
        Session["havelogined"] = "1";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>location.replace('Default.aspx')</script>");
}
else{
//do something
}
```

---

However in the login.aspx,after I enter the name and password,then click the login button,I was redirected to Default.aspx in the address bar of the browser,but I can not see the content of the Default.aspx,I just see:

---

Access is denied.
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2................

---

So I wonder how does the asp.net's authentication know if I am logined or not? Can I repace these notice with some readable information?

Also,

```
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

What does the "users" here mean?

I do not think they are the registered users in my database.

Comment: You must be frustrated, if you're swearing in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 401.2 status code corresponds to "No Authentication method configured".   I'll need more info to confirm.  If I had to guess I'd say you are missing the <[forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)> tag under  the <[authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e.aspx)> tag.

If you haven't already found this article,  you might try this link which talks about how to fully setup forms authentication - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx

the

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

means allow all users.  In essence it is instructing ASP.NET to allow all users (authenticated or unauthenticated) access to random_code_img.aspx

BTW:

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

means don't allow unauthenticated users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. 401.2 often occurs on IIS because anonymous authentication wasn't enabled.

Comment: @Naraen:I read the tutorial in the link you post,it works now,but I wonder how the "FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage" work? which page will it jump to if there is not a from page? I mean if I just enter Login.aspx,then I submit,how does the asp.net know which page to redirect?

Comment: @hguser - It uses the returnUrl queryString parameter to determine which page to redirect to.  From what I recall, if you go to the login page directly, the returnURL will default to "/"  which would be your home page.  Is that what you are seeing to?

Comment: But I have set the start page of my application to "Login.aspx" since all the pages are protected except the "login.aspx",but after I submit,the broswer jump to default.aspx(In fact I have a Default.aspx).

Comment: Makes sense.  The start page is a Visual Studio setting for when you debug the application.  It is different from the default page as configured in the web server.   The web server by default is configured to interpret "/" as "Default.aspx".

Comment: Cool.  Glad it helped.  Would you mind upvoting/accepting the answer?

Comment: Hi:I just found that if I deploy my application in the iss,it works fine(at least the authentication),but if I debug my appliation using vs2010,I found that when I try to visit the Login.aspx,the resources can not be accessed,I mean all the js/css/images inside the Login.aspx do not work. It seems that these static resource requests are also denied,isn't it?

Comment: Hmmm... Haven't seen that before.  That might be worth posting as a seperate question.  Somebody else might have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loginButton_click method, after you validate your user, you can simply use

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`

See here for more information and example . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx